# Respond.js CDN/X-Domain Setup

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, cross-domain, media-queries

I'm trying to get [respond.js](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond) working with their CDN/X-Domain instructions but falling short. In IE8 no media queries are loaded still.

I even uploaded the example `cross-domain` folder to test and adjusted the paths to the files

In my `<head>` I have:

```
<link href="http://mywebsite.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/respond-proxy.html" id="respond-proxy" rel="respond-proxy" />
<link href="http://mywebsite.com/respond.proxy.gif" id="respond-redirect" rel="respond-redirect" />
<script src="http://mywebsite.com/respond.proxy.js"></script>
```

- I'm linking to the respond.js itself just before the files above
- media queries work in ie8 when the CDN is turned off
- There are no errors being outputted by IE8
- I'm hosted with WPEngine and they have added the respond-proxy.html to the CDN on their end. - I've double checked the files and they all exist.

Comment: If you haven't already seen it, this page has the most comoprehensive info I've found on respond.js + CDN: http://webdesign.web3.lu/mediaqueries_polyfill.html   Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

This is how I got it working, remote refers to a remote-url and local to a local asset.
Make sure to link to your stylesheets before calling respond.js.

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src='//remote/respond.min.js'></script>
  <link href="//remote/respond-proxy.html" id="respond-proxy" rel="respond-proxy" />
  <link href="/local/respond.proxy.gif" id="respond-redirect" rel="respond-redirect" />
  <script src="/local/respond.proxy.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: The weird thing is that some css stop working... Now going to dig into font-face bug. Even this bunch of techniques worked with https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/39519/webfontsdemo/index.html